# Italic tag not being formatted in Github Pages

Tags: html, css, github-pages, italic

I'm working on a webpage with Github Pages, and I wrote `<li> alpha <i>beta</i> </li>` in a Markdown file, which is used to create the html page. The following pictures are 1- what I see in the inspect box, while on the page, and 2-What is visible on the webpage. "beta" should be in italic, but isn't formated somehow. Is this a known issue, am I doing something wrong?

[image: One]
[image: Two]

Comment: Since it's a Markdown file, why not use Markdown syntax? `_foobar_`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to get the italic format of text you should use css. According to MDN:

> "... A browser will typically still display the contents of the 
>   element in italic type, but is, by definition, no longer required
>   to..."

And:

> Typically this element is displayed in italic type. However, it should
>   not be used simply to apply italic styling; use the CSS font-style
>   property for that purpose.

you can read more about the `i` element [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/i).

Answer (score 0):

use `font-style: italic;` on element in css styles. this should work best.

Answer (score 0):

The code you've taken a screenshot of will, **by default**, render `<i>beta</i>` in italic.

The most likely reason that it hasn't is some CSS setting `font-style: normal` on the `i` elements. Possibly this is part of an over-eager global CSS reset that sets `* { font-style: normal; }`.

Either:

- Remove the CSS setting that style *or*
- Override it for the `i` element